# How to create QML button, which emits a constant signal while its pressed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml, pyside2

I have a joystick with 4 buttons.

I need to call some short singleshot increment function again and again while i hold a button, so, i need a button, which emits a constant signal, while pressed.

I've tried `onPressAndHold`, but it's just emits only one signal after certain amount of time, when I need to emit a constant signal via pressing the button. (i just want to call a singleshot function every certain amount of time).

Of cource i can write a 'flag' button, which will start the function with a loop, which will work until flag is changed with `onReleased` method. But, i don't want to rewrite the function + using loops is not good for this project bc of it's overloaded architecture.

Comment: Signals are function calls. There can be no "constant function call". There can be signal for button press and button release, and you can hook up a timer to buttons pressed staye so you get timer timeout signals at some frequency while button is pressed (this is probably a bad idea of you don't actually need to do something like have a blinking light). So, what is the end result you actually want?

Comment: @hyde, its a robotic arm project. Programmers, who were before me, wrote some backend functions, which increment the coordinates of an arm by one (this is justified by the architecture of the incremental motor of the robot). So, i need to transfer signals from joystick to robot. (i send actual joystick values (coordinates) to the robot every 10 ms, as example, and robot move himself to these coordinates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [autoRepeat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html#autoRepeat-prop) and [autoRepeatDelay](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html#autoRepeatDelay-prop).

```
Button {
    text: "Press"
    autoRepeat: true
    autoRepeatDelay: 100

    onPressed: console.log("pressing")
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement this method to button, which realised via mouse_area method?

Comment: When using a `MouseArea` I would suggest the solution by Jürgen as only `AbstractButton` has `autoRepeat` functionality.

Comment: thank you for your help! i just figured out that it's also not possible to use methods like `onPositionChanged`. Is it possible to protect some methods from repeating? Like, method `onPressed` will be repeated, but method `onReleased` or `onPositionChanged` will be called only once, in the end?

Comment: oh, onPositionChanged is MouseArea's method... looks like a problem)

Comment: `autoRepeat` is only for press and holding the button down. You can however create a Timer for each signal you want to repeat similar to what Jürgen did.

Comment: just decided to use `onPressedChanged` instead `MouseArea` + `onPositionChanged`. Also, it's not necessary to use `onRelease` anymore. Btw, thank you for your help!)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned from @hyde you can use a Timer and start/stop it accordingly:

```
Timer {
    id: timer
    interval: 100
    repeat: true

    onTriggered: {
        console.log("trigger");
    }
}

Button {
    text: "Press"

    onPressed: {
        timer.start();
    }

    onReleased: {
        timer.stop();
    }
}
```